# CSS elements adjust when a: hover

Tags: css, hover

I Have a `<li>` menu items with 2px border bottom as underline and a bold hover which makes other elements move while hovering. I tried to change the padding on the hover but without a result. (I think the problem is the added underline of border bottom)

```
#menu { 
     list-style: none outside none;
     margin-top:40px; 
     text-align: center}

#menu li { 
     margin-right: 26px;
     display:inline;}

#menu a:hover {
     border-bottom:2px solid #ac9962;
     font-size:16px;
     letter-spacing: -2px;
     white-space: nowrap;
     font-weight:bold;}

<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Menu4</a></li>
      </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tGcfh/

Comment: The problem is the bold more than anythng. Which _of course_ will change the balance of the menu. Consider using a different hover state ir adjusting the padding on the containing element to counter the bold text's displacement.

Comment: the list items dont have a defined height or width to them so they are being sized by the nested text, and when you hover the font size increases as well as the bold increasing the list item size, and since they are displayed: inline this changes the size across the whole menu moving the other items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar:

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu_container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu_container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#menu_container ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
}

#menu_container ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#menu_container ul li a:hover {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

This will work perfectly as expected, but have in mind that display:table is not supported in IE7 and bellow.

Answer (score 0):

make the font size same in hover time and normal time on hover time font-size:16px is there and normal time font-size:14px is there... and hover time font weight bold is there.

Answer (score 0):

just give the following css for hover. You have gave bold, border bottom and size change, it causes alignment issue. Otherwise you have to give specified width to each link.

```
#menu2 a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if change this

```
#menu a:hover {
border-bottom:2px solid #ac9962;
font-size:16px;
letter-spacing: -2px;
white-space: nowrap;
font-weight:bold;}
```

delete

```
font-size:16px;
letter-spacing: -2px;
font-weight:bold;
```

This may fix your problem